# Generating class for dynamic XML

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an xml strucutre like below

```
<projectname>
    <packagename>
        <classname>
            <targetmethodname>
                <testmethod1>
                    <parameter1>--</parameter1>
                    <parameter2>--</parameter2>
                </testmethod1>
                <testmethod2>
                    <parameter1>--</parameter1>
                    <paramater2>--</parameter2>
                </testmethod2>
                <testmethodname>
                --------------
                ------------
                ----------------
                </testmethodname>
            </targetmethodname>
        </classname>
    </packagename>
</projectname>
```

XML structure changes dynamically based on user input.
My question is how can I generate this by using JAXB. What would be the class structure for this xml.

Comment: What do you mean by "structure changes dynamically based on user input"? Would you get different tag name?

Comment: yeah.for different parameters  the tags will be changed.i am trying to generate an xml from a swing window that will contain all package names and class names method names.user will select any of them through the dropdown.once he click submit xml should be generated.

Comment: Ok, then look at @XmlElementRef http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html

Answer (score -1):

You have to write a xsd schema corresponding to your xml structure, and then use the xjc tool to generate beans.

You should also take a look on XMLEncoder http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html, maybe it could help you.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but your answer is misleading. You don't _have_ to write an XML Schema for this, annotated classes would suffice.

Also, "link-only" answers are generally discouraged.